# zlib.inflate returns Error: unknown compression method

Tags: javascript, zlib

I am trying to use zlib.inflate to unzip this data (which has definitely been zipped with zlib):

My use of zlib.inflate is very simple but not working:

```
var input = '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'

var compression = zlib.inflate(input, (err, buffer) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(buffer.toString('hex'));
    }
    else {
        console.log(err)
    }
    
})
```

Does anyone know how to make zlib inflate the input without returning an error?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your date a hex string? You need to convert it to a buffer and pass that buffer to `zlib.inflate(...)` instead of the string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably a bit late, but for anyone interested, try the pako library (it's simplified gzip)
https://nodeca.github.io/pako/
super easy string compression and decompression

I use it to compress json for further storage in local storage. Life saver when JSON is too large and local storage exceeds memory limit (the quota exceeded errors)

Example:

```
// stringify, compress with gzip and save to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('posts', pako.gzip(JSON.stringify(foundPosts)));
// after saving to localstorage the Uint8Array gets converted to a string so we need to split it before decompression
const posts = JSON.parse(pako.ungzip(localStorage.getItem('posts').split(','), { to: 'string' }));
```

I hope this helps the stray seekers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the hexadecimal into binary first.

Comment: Converted to binary but now receive this error:Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib.zlibOnError [as onerror] (zlib.js:187:17) {
  errno: -3,
  code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR'
}

Comment: Then you did it wrong. `78 9c` is a valid zlib header.

Comment: Though something else is wrong with that deflate data after the header.